# My Junit test isn't working

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TextAnalysisTest { 

        @Test
        public void testNumberRange(){
        //if i put a number between 1-4 here - Junit will pass the test
        //if not - Junit will fail

        int [] input = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int min = 1;
        int max = 4;
        assertEquals(input).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(min).isLessThanOrEqualTo(max);

            System.out.println("test finished");
        }


}
```

I'm a novice to Java and really trying to learn. Could anybody help me with this solution?  thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I want the user to put in a number between 1-4 so the test will pass and if they don't it will throw an error.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting and try this 
assertTrue(input[0] >= min && input[length-1] <= max);

Comment: It is saying there is a problem with the assertEquals(input) line. It says it is only applicable for objects in integers

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the array and prove, that every single value is between min and max.

Answer (score 0):

Make the input single int, not array[].
And you have to fix assertEquals logic.

```
class TextAnalysisTest {

    @Test
    public void testNumberRange(){    
    int input = 2;
    int min = 1;
    int max = 4;
    assertTrue(input>=min);
    assertTrue(input<=max);
    System.out.println("test finished");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class TextAnalysisTest {

    @Test
    public void testNumberRange(){
    //if i put a number between 1-4 here - Junit will pass the test
    //if not - Junit will fail

    int [] input = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int min = 1;
    int max = 4;
    for(int k:input){
assertEquals(k).isGreaterThanOrEqualTo(min).isLessThanOrEqualTo(max);


}
 System.out.println("test finished");
    }
}
```